# Does registering bean inside @Component class respect @Scope?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

This [website](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/bean-definition-in-components.html) says beans registered inside component classes are not cglib proxied and do not go through the spring container. So does this mean if I register a bean inside a component class (snippet below), adding @Scope("request") wont make any difference, and a new instance of `AnotherBean` will always be created whenever `testBean.anotherBean()` is called from some external class?

```
@Component
public class TestBean {

  @Bean
  @Scope("request")
  public AnotherBean anotherBean() {
    return new AnotherBean();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bean that is not cglib proxied is the `@Component` itself, not the bean registered using the `@Bean` annotation. If you are not calling the anotherBean method explicitly, it won't make a difference because the proxy is used to return the bean when the method annotated with `@Bean` is called. See the example

The bean `testBeanComponent` is not cglib proxied :

```
@Component
public class TestBeanComponent {

  @Bean
  @Scope("request")
  public AnotherBeanComponent anotherBeanComponent() {
    return new AnotherBeanComponent();
  }
}
```

The bean `testBeanConfiguration` is cglib proxied :

```
@Configuration
public class TestBeanConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Scope("request")
  public AnotherBeanConfiguration anotherBeanConfiguration() {
    return new AnotherBeanConfiguration();
  }
}
```

What it mean :

```
@Service
public class TestService {

  @Autowired //Inject a normal bean
  private TestBeanComponent testBeanComponent;     

  @Autowired //Inject a proxy
  private TestBeanConfiguration testBeanConfiguration;

  public void test() {
    //Calling anotherBeanComponent always return a new instance of AnotherBeanComponent
    testBeanComponent.anotherBeanComponent()
      .equals(testBeanComponent.anotherBeanComponent()); // is false

    //Calling anotherBeanConfiguration return the bean managed by the container
    testBeanConfiguration.anotherBeanConfiguration()
      .equals(testBeanConfiguration.anotherBeanConfiguration()); // is true
  }
}
```

But if you are injecting the bean instead of using the method, everything will work as you expected :

```
@Service
public class TestService2 {

  @Autowired //Inject a proxy with scope request
  private AnotherBeanComponent anotherBeanComponent;     

  @Autowired //Inject a proxy with scope request
  private AnotherBeanConfiguration anotherBeanConfiguration;

}
```